# SSL cert errors for certain browsers. How can I find out what SSL features old browsers don't support, which my site relies on?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, ssl-certificate-errors

The [SSL Server test from ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) will test your HTTPS server and give you a score on how well your HTTPS server is set up. You can use that results to get the most secure HTTPS server.

I have a HTTPS server that works in my browser, but a client has sent screenshots of SSL errors from their Android browser. And I have to fix it and I'm not sure how.

Is there any site that has a list/database of all the quirks, and supported (or not supported) features, for various browser/OSs, and I can point it at a HTTPS server and it can tell me "Oh you're using feature X, which isn't supported in browser Y". [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) tells me what HTML/CSS/JS features are supported in what browsers. I want something like that for HTTPS. sslabs tels me how to make a more secure HTTPS server, I need a more compatible, more widly useable, server.

Comment: The SSLLab report does much of that for you. It will tell you near the bottom what type of clients can connect, and why not.

Comment: @Drifter104 OH! I didn't see that. That might answer my question exactly. Can you enter that as a real question, and then I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running the [SSL Server test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) on SSL Labs, you will find a section called **Handsake Simulation**

It should look something like this, if a client isn't supported it will list a reason why. For example on this server IE8 on XP is not supported because it doesn't support SNI[image: Handsake Simulation]

Answer (score 1):

I use the the Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator:
https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/

good luck!